# reduxForm v5.3.1 uncontrolled/controlled warning on checkbox

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux-form

So, here is the warning:

```
Warning: UserInviteForm is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled.
```

After looking at [this](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/735) ticket for reduxForm v5 and others, It seems that I am getting this warning because the initial value for the field is undefined and so the input value attribute needs to be initialized with either the fields value || "".

Do a little further [research](https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/), controlled checkboxes need the checked attribute set to a value.

So my assumption is that the way to clear the warning would be to write the input tag in one of two ways:

```
<input
  {...isPrimary}
  value={isPrimary.value || ''}
  type="checkbox"
>
```

OR

```
<input
  {...isPrimary}
  checked={isPrimary.checked || ''}
  type="checkbox"
>
```

For good measure I also tried `checked={isPrimary.checked || false}` and `value={isPrimary.value || false}` and the combination of both together.

I even tried setting the checked and value property of the `isPrimary` on component mount but still nothing can get rid of the warning.

Also, I want to add, I know that there is a reduxForm v6 out, but this is the current version of our deployed app that we are working to fix and reduxForm v6 is coming in a future deployment version of our app.

Anyone got any insight to solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried one more thing and figured out the solution.

I was able to get this to work by setting the initial value of the field when connecting the reduxForm, then set the value of the input to that intitial value.

```
UserInviteFormContainer = reduxForm({
 form: FORM_ID,
   fields: FIELD_NAMES,
   initialValues: {
     isPrimary: false,
   },
   validate,
})(UserInviteFormContainer);


<input
 {...isPrimary}
 value={isPrimary.initialValue || ''}
 type="checkbox"
>
```